# Некоректная передача данных через сокеты

Tags: c++, сокет

**Суть проблемы**: когда я отправляю *серверу* или *клиенту* сообщение в длину больше чем в одно слово (Например: **"Hello client"**), то в переменную msg записывается только **"Hello"** и отправляется тоже **"Hello"**.

Я так полагаю, это проблема из-за `cin`, но я не знаю как можно обойтись без него.

Как можно решить эту проблему? И можно ли передавать данные через `string`, а не через `char buff[256]`?

***Код сервера:***

```
int main() {
    int sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8887);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton("192.168.0.60", &server_address.sin_addr);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(sock, 3);

    int client_sock;
    client_sock = accept(sock, 0, 0);
    char hello[256] = "Hello client";
    send(client_sock, &hello, sizeof(hello), 0);

    char buff[256];
    recv(client_sock, &buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    cout << buff << endl;

    char msg[256] = "";
    cout << "msg >> ";
    cin >> msg;
    send(client_sock, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    recv(client_sock, &buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    cout << buff << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

***Код клиента:***

```
int main() {
    int sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8887);
    inet_aton("192.168.0.60", &server_address.sin_addr);

    int con = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    char hello[256] = "Hello server";
    send(sock, &hello, sizeof(hello), 0);

    char buff[256];
    recv(sock, &buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    cout << buff << endl;

    char msg[256] = "";
    recv(sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    cout << msg << endl;

    cout << "msg >> ";
    cin >> msg;
    send(sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что полностью отсутствуют проверки возвращаемых значений.

Comment: @user7860670 Вы имеете в виду, что нехватает к примеру проверки на подключение?

Comment: В добавление к вышестоящему комментарию: std::cin >> считывает только одно слово. И да, данные можно передавать через std::string

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я пытался передавать через string, но всё время вместо сообщение выводилось: "Ошибка сегментации". Вполне возможно, что я делал что-то неправильно. Не могли бы показать, как использовать string с сокетами на примере?

Comment: @lakvak так а как вы пытаетесь передавать через string?

Comment: Вот так:
    string msg;
    cout << "msg >> ";
    getline(cin, msg)
    send(sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

Comment: @lakvak так у вас ошибка компиляции должна быть на этом месте. И компилятор должен вам сказать, что ожидается указатель на char, а вы передаёте указатель на std::string, ещё и с неверным размером. Хотя (так как я точно не помню сигнатур функций) если там принимается указатель на void, то все скомпилится, но тем не менее это грубая ошибаа

Comment: @lakvak в качестве пищи для размышлений: посмотрите чему равен ваш sizeof от std::string

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch С этим я более менее разобрался. Но всё же осталась проблема: В переменную `msg` записывается только 1 слово. Как это исправить?

Comment: @lakvak что значит как исправить? Ошибки сдесь нет - это абсолютно верное поведение, так что если вам нужно другое поведение, то опишите его

Comment: Я разобрался, извиняюсь! Нужно было вместо `cin` использовать `cin.getline(str, n)`